# How to parallelize 3 Two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

I need to check the best way to parallelize 3 two-dimensional arrays. Two of them (A and B) have values set in the for loop, and the other (the C) have the sum of A and B.

I have to use MPI to achieve what I want. I'm thinking in separate the process and check something like "If myrank == 0 then make that work", but I don't know if that is the best option. The code I have to parallelize is this:

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<1000; j=j+2) {
        A[i][j] = 1.0;
        A[i][j+1]=-1.0;
    }
}
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<1000; j++) {
        B[i][j] = 1.0;
        C[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
}
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<1000; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<1000; k++) {
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
}
result=0.0;
for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<1000; j++) {
        result=result+C[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you know about Parallelization ?

Comment: Is this code the real code? Do you want to parallelize the first 2 loops? What about your platform?

Comment: @Thomas Edited, N should be 1000 too. 
.

Comment: @LPs, yes it is. Is a snippet of the program that I have to use mpi to Parallelize..

Comment: A problem with parralelization is data racing. To avoid data racing in this particular case you could process `A` and `B` at the same time. Then process `C`, then calculate your result. Otherwise there is no way of knowing, whether a calculation on a particular element of `A` or `B` has finished.

Comment: @laurisvr So In your opinion I should use Scatter in A and B and then Gather to C?

Comment: @TCMSS Yes I think in this particular case that would be the solution.

Comment: Start by tossing out the pointless `C[i][j] = 0.0;`. Then later instead of `C[i][j] +=` use `C[i][j] =`.

Comment: A search for a term such as *MPI parallel array addition* will get you, much more quickly than is happening here, towards example programs that you can study and adapt to your requirements.  As it stands your question is borderline off-topic, showing no signs that you have tackled your problem yourself.

Comment: @Lundin no, you can't do that since C[i][j] is the sum of `A[i][k] * B[k][j]`

Comment: @Thomas So? It doesn't matter what value that is assigned to `C[i][j]`, the initialization to zero in a separate loop is still pointless. Move it into one of the outer loops before the assignment. Though of course little of this artificial code makes any sense in a real world application.

Comment: @Lundin : You seem to have missed the fact that there's a loop over k.

Comment: @TCMSSS - Google "MPI Matrix Multiplication" and you'll find many examples.

Comment: I already made it with BCAST and SCATTER, but I can't solve the problem of the size of the matrix can't be divisible by the number of processors. How can I solve this?